# Buscar por nombre en una tabla SQLite y extraer todos los datos de la fila

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

Con el siguiente código se obtienen los datos de la fila correspondiente al id introducido por el usuario.

```
   def buscarID():
        Conexion=sqlite3.connect("Clientes.db")
        baseCursor=Conexion.cursor()
        baseCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DATOSCLIENTE WHERE ID=" +var_dato.get()) 
        cliente=baseCursor.fetchall()
        var_observaciones.delete('1.0',END)
        for cliente in cliente:
            var_id.set(cliente[0])
            var_nombre.set(cliente[1])
            var_apellidos.set(cliente[2])
            var_dni.set(cliente[3])
            var_direccion.set(cliente[4])
            var_tlf.set(cliente[5])
            var_correo.set(cliente[6])
            var_observaciones.insert(1.0, cliente[7])
        Conexion.commit()
```

Lo que quiero conseguir, es crear una función que busque por nombre.He intentado de varias formas pero no he sido capaz.
La siguiente linea es una de ellas:

```
Cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DATOSCLIENTE WHERE NOMBRE=" +var_dato.get())
```

Da como resultado el siguiente error en la salida al buscar por nombre:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Maria

También he intentado con:

```
 baseCursor.execute("SELECT * FROM DATOSCLIENTE LIKE=" +var_dato.get())
```

¿Alguna solución o idea?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Estas armando un sql, y por lo tanto, las cadenas van entre comillas, no?

Comment: algo me dice que te falta meter el resultado que extrae tu cursor entre comillas simples: `baseCursor.execute("select * from datos cliente like '"+var_dato.get+"'")`

Comment: @RuslanLópez Ya he probado con  `execute("select NOMBRE from DATOSCLIENTE LIKE '"+var_dato.get()+"'") `  y   `execute("select * from DATOSCLIENTE LIKE '"+var_dato.get()+"'")`

Answer (score 0):

La solución al problema que he planteado es la siguiente:
 `Cursor.execute("select * from DATOSCLIENTE WHERE NOMBRE LIKE '"+var_dato.get()+"'")`

Devuelve: [(11, 'maria', 'soria', '2222', '', '', '', '\n')]

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).